# Cucumber feature showing error "No Route Matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have a feature file like this

```
Feature: search for movies by director

As a movie buff
So that I can find movies with my favorite director
I want to include and serach on director information in movies I enter

Background: movies in database

Given the following movies exist:
| title        | rating | director     | release_date |
| Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
| Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
| Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
| THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |

Scenario: add director to existing movie
When I go to the edit page for "Alien"
And  I fill in "Director" with "Ridley Scott"
And  I press "Update Movie Info"
Then the director of "Alien" should be "Ridley Scott"
```

Now I have a step definition like this which passes the Given the following movies exist: case.

```
Given /the following movies exist/ do |movies_table|
  movies_table.hashes.each do |movie|
  Movie.create!(movie)
end
```

end

But when cucumber runs the step When I go to the edit page for "Alien" it throws this error

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
>   (ActionController::RoutingError)
>   ./features/support/paths.rb:20:in `path_to'

My paths.rb has this Case in path_to

```
when /^the edit page for (.*)/
  m = Movie.find_by_title($1)
  edit_movie_path(m)
```

I checked that m is coming nil, but in the background i added four of the movies to the db. 
I have also checked **'rake routes'** but all routes are present.

Please help me understand, I am very new to rails and cucumber. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double quote is missing around `(.*)`
the

```
when /^the edit page for (.*)/
```

should be

```
when /^the edit page for "(.*)"/
```

**Explanation:**
Assuming that your **websteps.rb** is containing

```
When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

It means first it will get the url by calling `path_to('the edit page for "Alien"')`.
Hence the case you are handing in `path_to` function should extract out the name `Alien` only. As the double quotes are missing, the `$1` is containing `"Alien"` instead of only `Alien`. And the `find_by_title` is actually looking for a movie like below

```
m = Movie.find_by_title('"Alien"') # Doesn't exist for sure ;)
```

Comment: Thanks yes i found it passing "Alien" and '"Alien"' manually to the method.

Comment: Great... thnx to you too :) so you are also on saas course right? ;)

Comment: yes i am learning ruby for the first time and the course went very quick without much clarity

Comment: ya right... for newbies its a bit tough... but helps are always around :). best of luck.